# Are these the hairs of Lord Shiva that the cosmologists are hinting at?

Tags: shiva

> The solar system might be a lot hairier than we thought.
>
> A new study publishing this week in the Astrophysical Journal by Gary
>   Prézeau of NASA's Jet Propulsion Laboratory, Pasadena, California,
>   proposes the existence of long filaments of dark matter, or "hairs."
>
> Dark matter is an invisible, mysterious substance that makes up about
>   27 percent of all matter and energy in the universe. The regular
>   matter, which makes up everything we can see around us, is only 5
>   percent of the universe. The rest is dark energy, a strange phenomenon
>   associated with the acceleration of our expanding universe.
>
> Neither dark matter nor dark energy has ever been directly detected,
>   although many experiments are trying to unlock the mysteries of dark
>   matter, whether from deep underground or in space.

Read the full news [here](http://www.nasa.gov/feature/jpl/earth-might-have-hairy-dark-matter).Another source  : [Earth could be surrounded by a "hairy" dark matter](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3330834/Earth-surrounded-hairy-dark-matter-Nasa-discovery-finally-help-astronomers-detect-elusive-substance.html)

Now,as we know, one of the 108 names of Lord Shiva is "Vyomkesha" meaning whose Kesh(hair) is the Vyom(the space,sky).See this [link](http://www.drikpanchang.com/hindu-names/gods/lord-shiva/108-shiva-names.html) for Lord Shiva's 108 names.

So,are the physicists hinting at Lord Shiva's hair?And isn't the co relation between Lord Shiva & Dark Matter/energy is getting a big scientific boost?

Comment: Scientific speculation is not allowed on this site, so I'm closing your question.

Comment: @Rickross Now read [Shiva Tandava Stotram](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/sri_shiva-shiva_tandava_stotram.php) and you understand it in different way. Anyways, Shiva is highly metaphorical and allegorical.